# How do I make JS code not affect other DIV?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi I am try to make a list of item, I have "add" and "minus" button for each item. The problem is that the JS code I had control two items together. ex. if I click "add" for item1, then the item2 gets added as well.

Looks like that my JS functions works for all button elements. So when I click a "button" element, all buttons get triggered.

How can I do add them individually?

PS: I guess I need to do something like a specific ID for JS to trigger. My thought is add a unique ITEM ID for each one and trigger the button under that specific ID so other buttons under other ITEM ID don't get triggered.

Here is my HTML code:

```
<div class="row bb">
    <div class="col-xs-12 food-container">
        <a href="#"><img src="img/1.png" class="min-w img-responsive" /></a>
        <div class="food-detail">
            <div class="food-name">test</div>
            <div class="food-sales">test：233333</div>
            <div class="food-price">
                ￥50
                <div class="food-edit">     
                    <button class="btn btn-info" value="50.55" id="minus">-</button>
                    <span class="num-sales"></span>
                    <button class="btn btn-info" value="50.55" id="add">+</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row bb">
    <div class="col-xs-12 food-container">
        <a href="#"><img src="img/1.png" class="min-w img-responsive" /></a>
        <div class="food-detail">
            <div class="food-name">test</div>
            <div class="food-sales">test:233333</div>
            <div class="food-price">
                ￥50
                <div class="food-edit">
                    <button class="btn btn-info" value="50.55" id="minus">-</button>
                    <span class="num-sales"></span>
                    <button class="btn btn-info" value="50.55" id="add">+</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is my JS:

```
var theTotal = 0;
var theSales = 0;
var minusButton = document.getElementById('minus');

if (theSales == 0) {
    $(minusButton).hide();
}

$('button').click(function () {
    var ID = this.id;

    if (ID == "add") {
        $(minusButton).show();
        theTotal = Number(theTotal) + Number($(this).val());
        theSales++;

        var num = theTotal.toFixed(2);

        $('.total').text("￥" + num); 
        $('.total-num-of-sales').text(theSales + "份"); 
        $('.num-sales').text(theSales);
    };

    if (ID == "minus") {
        theTotal = Number(theTotal) - Number($(this).val());
        theSales--;
        var num = theTotal.toFixed(2);

        if ( theSales == 0 ) {
            $('.total').text(""); 
            $('.total-num-of-sales').text(""); 
            $('.num-sales').text("");
            $(minusButton).hide();
        }
        else if ( theSales > 0 ) {
            $('.total').text("￥"+num); 
            $('.total-num-of-sales').text(theSales + "份");
            $('.num-sales').text(theSales);
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: First of All `ID` should be unique across complete page.

Comment: you're using classes which is not a good idea also you have duplicate ID's when you only want to manipulate one area, you could use a class selector though.. something to specify classes within an id.. for ex `$("#add .total")` or `$("#minus .total")` with a rework of `ID` wrappers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use multiple id on same page

http://jsfiddle.net/bjc1c9tr/4/

Check this will help you

```
 var theTotal = 0;
var theSales = 0;
var minusButton = $('.minus');
if (theSales == 0) {
    $(minusButton).hide();
}

$('button').click(function(){
    var ID = $(this).attr('data');

    if (ID == "add") {
        $(this).parent().find('.minus').show();
        theTotal = Number($(this).parent().find('.num-sales').text()) + Number($(this).val());
        theSales = Number($(this).parent().find('.num-sales').text()) + Number(1);
        var num=theTotal.toFixed(2);
         $(this).parent().find('.total').text("￥"+num); 
         $(this).parent().find('.total-num-of-sales').text(theSales+"份"); 
         $(this).parent().find('.num-sales').text(theSales);
    };
    if (ID == "minus") {
            theTotal = Number($(this).parent().find('.num-sales').text()) - Number($(this).val());
            theSales= Number($(this).parent().find('.num-sales').text()) - Number(1);
            var num=theTotal.toFixed(2);
            if ( theSales == 0) {
                 $('.total').text(""); 
                 $(this).parent().find('.total-num-of-sales').text(""); 
                 $(this).parent().find('.num-sales').text("");
                 $(this).parent().find('.minus').hide();
            }
            else if ( theSales > 0) {
                 $(this).parent().find('.total').text("￥"+num); 
                 $(this).parent().find('.total-num-of-sales').text(theSales + "份")
                 $(this).parent().find('.num-sales').text(theSales);

            }

    };

 });
```

html (added new classes)

```
   <div class="row bb">
                                    <div class="col-xs-12 food-container">
                                        <a href="#"><img src="img/1.png" class="min-w img-responsive" /></a>
                                        <div class="food-detail">
                                            <div class="food-name">test</div>
                                            <div class="food-sales">test：233333</div>
                                            <div class="food-price">￥50
                                                <div class="food-edit">

                                                    <button class="btn btn-info minus" value="50.55" data="minus">-</button>
                                                    <span class="num-sales"></span>
                                                    <button class="btn btn-info add" value="50.55" data="add">+</button>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                            </div>
                                <div class="row bb">
                                        <div class="col-xs-12 food-container">
                                            <a href="#"><img src="img/1.png" class="min-w img-responsive" /></a>
                                            <div class="food-detail">
                                                <div class="food-name">test</div>
                                                <div class="food-sales">test:233333</div>
                                                <div class="food-price">￥50
                                                    <div class="food-edit">
                                                        <button class="btn btn-info minus" value="50.55" data="minus">-</button>
                                                        <span class="num-sales"></span>
                                                        <button class="btn btn-info add" value="50.55" data="add">+</button>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('button').click(function(){
var ID = this.id;
if (ID == "add") {
    $(minusButton).show();
    theTotal = Number(theTotal) + Number($(this).val());
    theSales = Number($(this).parent().find('.num-sales').text())+1;
    var num=theTotal.toFixed(2);
     $('.total').text("￥"+num); 
     $('.total-num-of-sales').text(theSales+"份"); 
    $(this).parent().find('.num-sales').text(theSales);
};

if (ID == "minus") {
        theTotal = Number(theTotal) - Number($(this).val());
    theSales = Number($(this).parent().find('.num-sales').text())-1;
        var num=theTotal.toFixed(2);
        if ( theSales == 0) {
             $('.total').text(""); 
             $('.total-num-of-sales').text(""); 
            $(this).parent().find('.num-sales').text("");
             //$('.num-sales').text("");
             $(minusButton).hide();
        }
        else if ( theSales > 0) {
             $('.total').text("￥"+num); 
             $('.total-num-of-sales').text(theSales + "份");
             $(this).parent().find('.num-sales').text(theSales);
             //$('.num-sales').text(theSales);

        }

};
```

$(this).parent().find('.num-sales').text(theSales); 
 By this way you can get the parent of clicked button and change the value of .num-sales of the selected parent

https://jsfiddle.net/s2u9eb36/ refer this one

Comment: I'll quickly suggest the .closest(selector) function from jQuery here, I found it much cleaner and robust than using .parent(), as it enables you to nest your elements deeper without having to redo code. https://api.jquery.com/closest/

Comment: $(this).closest('div').find('.num-sales').text(theSales); A good suggestion. Thanks @WardD.S.

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing the elements because of your id and class selectors.

When you select elements through jQuery by class (like `$('.num-sales')`), jQuery gives you *a collection of all elements that match* the selector. In your case, that would be both `class="num-sales"` elements.

Whenever you then call a function (like `.html(theSales)`), it will apply that function *to each element in the collection*, that's why your code is affecting more than one element.

You will need to find a way to distinguish one element of the other. There's quite a few options here, but I like doing it by limiting the scope of my selectors. With this I mean I would first find the `food-detail` div that contains the clicked element, and then find `.num-sales` etc... only within that element.

Then you can do the following in your button clicks:

```
$('button').click(function(){
    var ID = this.id;
    var element = $(this) //make a jQuery object of the clicked button

    // finds the first parent element with class food-detail
    var container = element.closest('.food-detail');

    // find .num-sales within container
    var numSales = container.find('.num-sales') 

   // continue...
});
```

in short:

1. when a button is clicked, find the food-detail div the button is in
2. .find in only that container instead of using selectors on the entire document

Edit: you should really change the `id="Add"` and `id="minus"` on your buttons, ids should be unique on the entire document. You can simply add `add` or `minus` as a class instead and check for it with `element.hasClass('add')`.

Comment: very useful suggestions! Thanks!