# Expand a toggled Div on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a page which has a number of collapsed DIVs showing content. I want to be able to link to this page and have the relevant DIV already open. E.g. `<a href="\page#B">Read about Section 2</a>"`. This is the code I have to control the collapse and expand.

```
<script>
jQuery(function ($) {
$(".header").click(function () {

$header = $(this);
$span = $header.find(">:first-child"),
//getting the next element
$content = $header.next();
//open up the content needed - toggle the slide- if visible, slide up, if not slidedown.
$content.slideToggle(500)
if ($span.text() == "-")
        $span.text("+")
    else {
        $span.text("-")
    }
});
});
</script>

<div class="container">
<div class="header" id="A">
    <span>+</span>  
          <h2>Section1</h2>
          </div>
<div class="content" id="B">
          I'm the content for section 1.
</div>
<div class="header">
    <span>+</span>  
          <h2>Section 2</h2>
          </div>
<div class="content">
          I'm the content for Section 2
</div>

</div> <!--- /container -->
```

Comment: So what's the actual issue? What have you tried that isn't working?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31831236/how-do-i-make-js-code-not-affect-other-div/31832197#31832197

Comment: You're looking for [`:target`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3Atarget).

Comment: which div is your according clickable header?

Comment: can you provide fiddle demo for better understanding.

Comment: @locateganesh here's the actual site: http://www.bloggshairdesign.co.uk/ the tile that talks about colour consultants should go to the prices page and ideally the colour consultation tab would be opened.

Answer (score 0):

Get id from url and then call click function to open this on document ready

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var id  = location.search.split('page=')[1];
//find div of according clickable header. not sure which is in your code
$($("#"+id).prev()).trigger("click");
});
```

Comment: This didn't work, @farhan. I wonder whether trying to make it generic hindered! The proper site is above. If you get chance to have another look that would be fantasatic.

Comment: Can you send me direct link where you are having issue